# Testing a Directly Attached Array in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid

I have an older 13 disk promise array that attaches to a server with SCSI.  We want to reuse this for our Exchange 2003 databases.  Is there Windows software (preferably free of course) that would stress test this.  Ideally, it would mimic writes and reads to large files in the way Exchange would.  Also I would like something that would run these stress tests constantly for a period of a week or two.

Thank you,
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free MS tool [jetstress](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Disk-Performance-Testing-Jetstress-2007.html) simulates Exchange disk usage of both the mail stores and the transaction logs.

Answer (score 2):

We used to use [IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org/) for this sort of thing. It used to be maintained by Intel but I think they dropped it and it's now opensource.

Answer (score 2):

How about SQLIOStress or it's replacement SQLIOSim? See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231619 for details. These apps simulate SQL Server and this should be a pretty similar to the load Exchange creates.

John Rennie

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [iozone](http://www.iozone.org/) and also [iometer](http://www.iometer.org/). I'm sure one of these will give you most of what you're looking for.